# Ordinal arithmetic $(\omega+2)²$

Tags: arithmetic, ordinals

I noticed $(\omega+2)*2$ had some pretty weird results:
\begin{align}
(\omega+2)*2 & = (\omega+2)+(\omega+2) \\
& = \omega+(2+\omega)+2 \\
& = \omega+\omega+2 \\
& = \omega2+2 \\
\end{align}

So I wonder how $(\omega+2)²$ behaved:
$$(\omega+2)^2 = (\omega+2)*(\omega+2)$$
but I don't know how the order of the distributive-ity works here like:
$$(\omega+2)*(\omega+2) = (\omega+2)*\omega + (\omega+2)*2$$
or:
$$(\omega+2)*(\omega+2) = \omega*(\omega+2) + 2*(\omega+2)$$
I think $(\omega+2)*\omega = \omega^2$ because the $+2$ gets consumed by the infinite additions.
But $(\omega*(\omega+2) = \omega^2+\omega2$ because you reach $\omega^2$ and than still have some left over.

A similar explanation can be applied too:
$$(ω+2)∗2=(ω+2)+(ω+2)=ω2+2$$
$$2∗(ω+2)= 2+2+...+2 \text{ ($\omega+2$ times)} = \omega+2$$

### Concrete

So which of these equations is correct?
And how does distribution work on ordinals?

Comment: [Distributive law on the left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication), that is, $\alpha(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt If you had put that in an answer I could have accepted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinal arithmetic follows the [distributive law on the left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_arithmetic#Multiplication), that is,

$$\alpha(\beta+\gamma)=\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma$$

In your case this means

$$(\omega+2)^2=(\omega+2)(\omega+2)=(\omega+2)\omega+(\omega+2)2=\omega^2+\omega2+2$$